# Помогите решить задачу на дп пожалуйста

Tags: c++, динамическое-программирование

Кузнечик сидит на кочке с номером 1. Он хочет добраться до кочки номер n. С каждой кочки кузнечик может прыгать в кочку с номером на 1 или на 3 больше текущей. Каким количеством способов кузнечик может добраться из первой кочку на кочку номер n?
Так как ответ может быть слишком большим, выведите его по модулю 10^9+7

**Входные данные**
В единственной строке дано целое число n (1≤n≤10^6)

**Выходные данные**
Выведите ответ по модулю 10^9+7

Пишет неправильный ответ на тесте

Мой код:'''

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<unsigned long long> F(n, 0);
    F[0] = 1;
    F[1] = 1;
    F[2] = 1;
    for (int i = 3; i < n; i++) {
        F[i] = F[i - 1] + F[i - 3];
    }
    std::cout << F[n - 1] % 1000000007;
    return 0;
}
```

'''

Comment: попробуйте приравнивать `F[i]` к остатку от деления на 10^9+7 на каждой итерации цикла `for`(скорее всего у вас просто получается слишком большое число, выходящее за границы типа)

Comment: также, в дальнейшем вообще не советую в `cout` делать подобные операции, он их может неправильно интерпретировать и вывести абсолютно неожиданный для вас ответ.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy потому, что на первую ступеньку можно попасть только одним способом (нумерация с нуля)

Comment: И еще одна рекомендация — давать URL проверяющей системы, чтобы можно было экспериментировать :) Давать **ответ**, не имея возможности его надежно проверить — слишком самонадеянно...

Comment: кстати. упражнение - сделать решение за  O(log N) вместо O(N) тут это не сильно важно, но в целом полезно будет.

Comment: @Harry просто я решал такую же задачу с такой же проблемой, но на следующий раз учту :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте приравнивать `F[i]` к остатку от деления на `10^9+7` на каждой итерации цикла `for` (скорее всего у вас просто получается слишком большое число, выходящее за границы типа)

```cpp
for (int i = 3; i < n; i++) {
        F[i] = (F[i - 1] + F[i - 3]) % (1e9+7);
}

cout << F[n - 1];
```

Примерно так. Также, в дальнейшем вообще не советую в cout делать подобные операции, он их может неправильно интерпретировать и вывести абсолютно неожиданный для вас ответ.

В остальном же, у вас все нормально.

Comment: Нормально, да не совсем. Вместо массива можно обойтись тремя последними значениями.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну, здесь согласен, памяти меньше занимать будет, но и этот вариант тоже имеет право на жизнь :)

Comment: Спасибо задача зашла. По поводу cout учту.